# Avoiding the need to cast in java inheritance

Tags: java

Lets say I had a simple inheritance structure like so:

```
class Shape {
   int id;
}

class Circle extends Shape {
   int radius;
}

class Square extends Shape {
   int length;
}

class ToyBox {
   List<Shape> shapes;
}
```

These objects cannot be augmented in any way (no adding methods/fields/accessors.change the file in any way) and should be treated as immutable/final. I have to return each of these shape objects to another part of the system I am working within with some extra information to go alongside each item. For example:

```
class extended Shape {
       int id;
}

class ExtendedCircle extends ExtendedShape {
    public Circle circle;
    public Blah circleStuff;
    public ExtendedCircle(Circle circle) {...}
}

class ExtendedSquare extends ExtendedShape {
    public Square square;
    public Blah squareStuff;
    public ExtendedSquare(Square square) {...}
}
```

The only way I can think of accomplishing this task given a ToyBox of shapes is to iterate through the shapes list, do an instance of check and do a cast to circle, square etc. to then construct each of the corresponding "Extended" objects. This makes me a little uncomfortable so i am wondering if there is another way to design such a system?

Comment: You could have an `ExtendedShapeFactory`.

Comment: Not clear to me what you're trying to achieve... What is `ExtendedShape` ? Why can't `Blah` be instantiated directly in `ExtendedCircle`'s constuctor for example ?

Comment: @Dici it is, i was just leaving out the non-relavent bits. Assume that each "extended" type object has some fields like Blah that it knows how to construct. The point is the conversion from regular Circle to ExtendedCircle given a list of super class List<Shape> shapes

Comment: Could each shape know how to build its extended form, perhaps given some additional parameters (which could be generic or abstract) ?

Comment: @Dici It could, but i was hoping to not couple them together in both directions

Comment: Maybe having a separate `Extended` concept doesn't make sense as well. This also doubles the amount of classes in your hierarchy. Why is it useful ? Could it be merged with the normal shapes ?

Comment: @Dici The reason for having the extended models is to vary the packaging of the internal shape objects depending on who I am returning them to. I could return them to Client A as ExtendedShape and to Client B as ExtraExtendedShape and each of these packaging could version separately. ExtraShape could contain a shape + the Blah data while ExtraExtendedShape could contain a shape + Fizz data (sorry for my bad naming)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155678/discussion-between-john-baum-and-dici).

Comment: @JohnBaum Can you add sample client code? not getting your use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to avoid casting and using `instanceof` operator you probably would like to consider using [Vistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) design pattern. Applying it to your example if might looks as following:

```
class Shape {
   int id;
   public void visitingShape(ToyBox box) {
       box.visitingShape(this);
   }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
   int radius;
   public void visitingShape(ToyBox box) {
       box.visitingCircle(this);
   }
}

class Square extends Shape {
   int length;
   public void visitingShape(ToyBox box) {
       box.visitingSquare(this);
   }
}

class ToyBox {
   List<Shape> shapes;

   public visitingShape(Shape shape) {
      // Do logic related to the shape
   }

   public visitingCircle(Circle shape) {
      // Do logic related to the circle
   }

   public visitingSquare(Square shape) {
     // Do logic related to the square
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes I did consider something like this. I just realized I left out a key requirement in my question. Editing it now, basically the shape/circle/square objects cannot be modified as they come from a third party api

Comment: Ok, but I guess you can decorate them implementing delegate, hence receiving control back in your hands.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! Can you leave an answer or edit the one above to illustrate how you see that working? Much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know, I'm still trying to get my head around the actual requirements, The visitor pattern is pretty inelegant and sometimes hard to read  if different visitors are used in different places. I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: @Dici, wondering in what way visitor is inelegant, this is pure OOP oriented pattern, leverages double dispatching and polymorphism.

Comment: I find it hard to tace because it's almost too decoupled. I prefer simple flows where you can read the code from top to bottom and understand what it does instead of needing to climb the call tree from the visitor method to the actual visitor that is called in the code path that's relevant to you.

Comment: @Dici IMO a way too subjective argument.

Comment: It's not subjective to say code should be easily traceable, is it ? Over-engineered, over-abstract code is hard to read in my experience, and I don't like unreadable code.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose an approach which is closer to pattern-matching. It doesn't solve the problem using inheritance, but it should give the same advantages  as a visitor pattern without the heavyweight aspect of it.

Simply introduce a `ShapeType` enumeration, make each shape return its type and use a `switch-case` structure to implement your logic. Might be more readable.

Comment: The shape can't return its type because they're effectively final.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding but it sounds like you're suggesting they have each `Shape` (`Circle`, `Square`,...) return its type. But they can't alter the shape classes in any way. Otherwise a fine solution.

Comment: I didnt quite understand the answer. Let's say each Shape returns its type when you do shape.getType(). Isnt the problem still that your Shapes are in their supertype form and (even if you know their type) you just save the instnace of checks and you still have to cast?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yeah you're right, this requirement wasn't in the question at first. My proposition is unapplicable indeed.

Comment: @JohnBaum enumerations allow implemening specific logic for specific enum values. It is ideal for cases where you have a limited number of cases. They're well-suited for containing data, and they're usually bad to implement logic (since they're statically initialized, you cannot inject any behaviour into it).

Is switching on an enumeration similar to casting ? Absolutely, but it's more robust and explicit. You can't easily find all casts in your codebase, but you can easily find all `switch` statements using your enum value. It is loose typing, but simle to use and readable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're in a pretty tough spot not owning the shape classes but I think you could add shape proxies. It adds an additional layer but provides the ability to extend the shapes as well as additional control over the interface if you'd need it.

Let's say, given a `Shape` as follows:

```
public class Shape {
    public void doSomethingWithShape() {}
}
```

You provide a `ShapeProxy` like so (implementing the `Shape` interface and providing a proxy into it):

```
public class ShapeProxy extends Shape implements IShapeProxy {
    // Optional
    @Override
    public void doSomethingWithShape() {
        // Do something extra if needed.
    }

    // From IShapeProxy
    @Override
    public ExtendedShape getExtended() {
        return new ExtendedShape(this);
    }
}
```

Likewise, you would have proxies for each additional shape:

```
public class CircleProxy extends Circle implements IShapeProxy {

    @Override
    public ExtendedCircle getExtended() {
        return new ExtendedCircle(this);
    }
}
```

And, of course, you could use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<IShapeProxy> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    shapes.add(new ShapeProxy());
    shapes.add(new CircleProxy());
    shapes.add(new SquareProxy());
    List<ExtendedShape> extendedShapes = new ArrayList<>();
    shapes.forEach(s -> extendedShapes.add(s.getExtended()));
}
```

I would prefer it this way but if you couldn't change the type of `List` then you could still shove them in as `Shape`s and cast to get the extended type. Still, it's a common cast that wouldn't require knowledge about the type of shape at hand.

---

***If that seems like too much*** or if you'd like to separate the extending from the proxy, you can combine the proxy idea with Dici's suggestion and add a type like so (changes to the interface not shown):

```
public enum ShapeType {
    SHAPE, CIRCLE, SQUARE
}

public class CircleProxy extends Circle implements IShapeProxy {
    // From IShapeProxy
    @Override
    public ShapeType getType() {
        return ShapeType.CIRCLE;
    }
}

// And...
for (IShapeProxy proxy : shapes) {
    switch (proxy.getType()) {
        case SHAPE:
            // Build the extended type.
            break;
        ...
        }
    }
}
```